# Securing REST API in microservices against Bots/Abuse via mass signups and "carding"

Tags: rest, bots, microservices

I have a backend (API, microservices) and mobile apps.

Mobile apps user same client_id (Oauth2).

Now I see many Bots signing up, adding credit card for checking them (carding)

I cannot throttle, limit them since the IP is always different also client_id for all mobile clients is the same.

What solutions would you propose to stop it? Different authentication?

If there is a way to identify each Mobile client uniquely I can throttle each for 1 request per second or something (to stop those automated Signup + Credit Card addition).

In the past fraudster created many accounts, but it could be also using one account (so I can also limit requests on it)

What are other solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the request and it's header to identify the mobile.
There is something called fingerprinting, you can either use something from the market or create a. Algorithm yourself.
You need to identify a pingerprint for each mobile and validate it in each request.